# All vectors of the form $(a, b, c)$, where $b = a + c + 2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Determined if this is a subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$

All vectors of the form $(a, b, c)$, where $b = a + c + 2$.

Comment: Please revise your question so that it is more readable mathematically. Of course this question is mathematical; just not in a good shape. :)

Comment: remember subspaces of $R_3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set of all vectors of the form $(a, b, c)$ such that $b = a + c + 2$. To show $S$ is a subspace of the linear space $\mathbb R$, it must satisfy the closure axioms:

- $\forall a, b \in S, a + b \in S$.
- $\forall a \in S, c \in \mathbb R, ca \in S$.

Looking at $S$, any two elements $x, y$ are of form $(a_1, b_1, c_1)$ and $(a_2, b_2, c_2)$, so $x + y = (a_1 + a_2, b_1 + b_2, c_1 + c_2)$.

By the given condition, this means $x + y = (a_1 + a_2, (a_1 + c_1 + 2) + (a_2 + c_2 + 2), c_1 + c_2) = (a_1 + a_2, a_1 + a_2 + c_1 + c_2 + 4, c_1 + c_2)$.

Because the second component does not satisfy the given equation $b = a + c + 2$, this subset is not a subspace.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** A subspace must contain $0$. Is $(0,0,0)$ of the form $(a,a+c+2,c)$?

Answer (score 0):

Donot forget that any of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is one of a following.
 $\{(0,0,0)\}$
 line through the origin.
plane through the origin.